# Div colors in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

what extension could show this side color?
How can i show this side color in the div classes?

Answer (score 3):

This is the **indent-rainbow** extension for VS Code.

Link: [rainbow-indent VS Code marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow)

You can install it from here or go to extensions in VS Code and search for **indent-rainbow** and press install.